How I can surface travel Philippines to Taiwan?
I am looking for anyone that can give me a hint on how to reach Taiwan from the Philippines without flying. I assume it will be either a cruise, a freight ship or a fishermen's boat. Anyone that can give me  a lead on where to ask? Last activity here on this subject is more than 10 years and inconclusive.

this is probably what you referred to from 10 years ago, but if not see https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/28991/how-to-leave-the-philippines-by-boat-to-taiwan-china-or-hong-kong

Yes indeed - it's inconclusive and probably out of date

This recent answer on another itinerary in the region states that freighter travel has all but disappeared since Covid.

On the south side, there is currently, apart from the Sandakan to Zamboanga RORO, running twice monthly on an  unpredictable schedule, a reliable weekly passenger Ferry between Tawi-Tawi (Bongao) and Lahad Datu in Malaysia. Crosses the Sulu area, be aware of government advice and take your conclusions from that. Contact and booking here https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100094586076738. Let's focus on the north side!

I don't know if there are any more direct links, but here's the closest I could get to on Google Maps:

Link
Note:

There are ferries from the Pingtan to Taiwan, but apparently Google Maps doesn't know about them. Rome2Rio does:

That makes the whole trip from Manila to Taipei possible using surface transportation only.

The Google Maps itinerary here is on foot, probably because some of the ferries/vessels are passenger-only (and Google Maps does not have public transport options for many parts of the trip)

Rome2Rio has public transport options for many of the parts, but you have to ask small bit by small bit, otherwise it will quickly switch to flights only. I haven't checked the whole itinerary, but once you are on the mainland things should be easier.

The ferry from Zamboanga (southern Philippines) to Sandakan (eastern Malaysia) only runs once a month

Using a car (+ferries), the part from Sandakan to Pingtan is estimated at over 170 hours. It's probably longer using public transport, and adding the parts from Manila and to Taipei, it's probably 2-3 weeks, possibly even a month.

There can be quite a few complications in terms of visas and other paperwork, especially if you want to drive (driving foreign cars in China is a challenge, I hear).


This probably wasn't the option you were looking for, but it shows it can be done!
