# Travel by sea from Manila

Tags: taiwan, manila

Has anyone here been successfully able to travel by sea from Manila to Taiwan? I read a post and some answers related to this topic that it could be done, but actual practice, I've been to the Manila International Container Terminal to see if I can tag along as a passenger but you can't even get past the main gate unless you are a worker or crew member. I don't think there are any more ferry boats either but if anybody knows of anything currently operational, please advise.
Thanks

Comment: The other question and the one mentioned in that (http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/543/is-it-possible-to-get-from-the-philippines-to-taiwan-to-japan-or-the-reverse-w ) do not have a good answer, in my view.

Comment: Unfortunately reasking the same question is unlikely to get any new answers for it.